# Bundling with Webpack for CLI application?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am trying to create a CLI application and would like to ship a single `bin.js` so my CLI tool has no external dependencies when installed.

I have a basic application written in TypeScript that uses `puppeteer-core`

```js
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core'

async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // ...
  })

  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://google.com')
  await new Promise(res => setInterval(res, 1000))
  browser.close()
}

main()
```

It works when run directly because the dependencies are fetched dynamically from `node_modules`.

When trying to bundle it I get a bunch of errors and an output `bin.js` that fails to run in node.

My `tsconfig.json` reads:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16"
  },
  "include": [
    "./cmd/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

and Webpack config is

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: false,
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'cmd', 'main.ts'),
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

I'm not really interested in bundling optimisations as I am just trying to include my dependencies with my CLI tool.

What's important for me is that the library files are concatenated so I can use them and distribute them along with my CLI applciation.

Is there a way to do this with Webpack?